# Creating a formula field based on thousands of zip codes

Tags: formula-field

I want to create a formula field that splits up California into two regions: North and South. The best way I can think to do this is by using lists of zip codes, which I have. The part I'm unclear of is how to take these lists of zips (more than 1,000 in each) and plug it into the formula field.

Essentially it would be if state = ca and zip = in array of 1,000 zips, region = North.

Any ideas?

Comment: Formula is probably not the best way here. I would just use a `List Custom Setting` and the corresponding `Apex Trigger` would be relatively lightweight. Something like `CA_North_Zips__c.getAll().containsKey(myZip)`.

Comment: Your questions makes me wonder why not use Geolocation features that are now native to the platform? Pick lat & long values to use as the "separation lines" and determine whether the latitude returned from the address/zip is `>=` or `<` the border value. The longitude would also need to be evaluated if you're going to follow an irregular path rather than a latitudinal line directly across the State. Food for thought...

Comment: @crmprogdev that sounds like exactly what I want, but I'm woefully ignorant of the geolocation features. After doing some quick searching I've found details on the geolocation field type, but am not sure if there's a native feature to populate that field based on existing address -- is that something that exists?

Comment: @crmprogdev nevermind -- I found the details in the release notes and saw they're not listed as fields, but are accessible via workflow rules and others. Thanks!

Comment: See https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_geolocate_overview.htm&language=en_US and https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000206753&language=en_US. They're custom fields. The best info will be found in the SOAP API docs. Once you create the fields, you can store the data. SF doesn't create or store them by default (yet).

Comment: as a hack, you can rely on 3 digit zips 940-949, 950-959 is Northern California, 910-919, 920-929 is Southern California; etc. See http://maps.huge.info/zip3.htm. Ten nested IFs might be all you need